# ConcurrentSkipListSet internal working, difference from TreeSet

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrentskiplistmap

Only difference I understand is between iterators. `SkipList` has **weakly consistent**, while `TreeSet` has **fail-fast**. Other than that I don't see any synchronized methods inside `SkipList` (although it is in Concurrent package).

Can someone please explain to me how is `SkipList` concurrent when it doesn't have any synchronization in it? What problems can it help me with and why should I ever use it other than this difference between Iterators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> „*…how is SkipList concurrent when it doesn't have any synchronization in it?…*“

***TL;DR*** — *`ConcurrentSkipListSet`* is ***concurrent*** because the elements it holds cannot be written to at the same time by ***concurrently*** executing threads. It achieves its *concurrency* without using *`synchronized`* and locks.

---

***The long version***

*Concurrency* in the context of the concurrent collections, does not necessarily mean those classes all implement thread safety using monitors (*aka, the `synchronized` keyword*).

First you should understand that thread safety is essentially about ensuring that two or more competing threads do not modify the shared state of an application. Then you realize that there are ways (*some more performant*) other than *`synchronized`* to achieve thread safety.

Making sure your state cannot be modified (*that it's immutable*) in the first place is one simple but very effective way to get thread safety.

Also, a class can be thread safe by *delegating* its thread safety responsibilities to a different, thread-safe class.

*`ConcurrentSkipListSet`* is considered to be ***concurrent*** because, as its Javadoc says, its: „[*Insertion, removal, update, and access operations **safely execute concurrently** by multiple threads*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html)“.

It achieves its *concurrency* because it [*delegates its thread safety responsibilities to a thread-safe class*](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/fb7064dc63f9/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.java#l141); namely: *`ConcurrentSkipListMap`*.

*`ConcurrentSkipListSet`* is thread-safe because *`ConcurrentSkipListMap`* is. And *`ConcurrentSkipListMap`* is thread-safe because, by using [*`AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<K,V>`*](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/fb7064dc63f9/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.java#l853) internally, it guarantees that none of its state (*its keys and values*) can be modified by currently executing threads, because its state is *immutable*.

You can see *`ConcurrentSkipListSet`* delegating to *`ConcurrentSkipListMap`* at several places in the source code I linked to above. If you're interested in learning more about *delegating thread safety*, I recommend you read [*Chapter 4, Composing Objects, Java Concurrency In Practice*](http://jcip.net/contents.html).

> „*…What problems can it help me with*“

Using it gets you *free* thread-safety. The kind that is way more performant — *and with way less risk of shooting yourself in the foot* — than using *`synchronized`*.

> „*…why should I ever use it other than this difference between Iterators?*“

If the state of your application needs to be stored in some collection and that collection will be accessible *in **any** way* to concurrently executing threads, then using *`ConcurrentSkipListSet`* is a thread-safe option that you have.

Comment: Thanks man! I hate to tell you this, but I don't quite get it. Can you please just shorten it in few sentences in comment section as I am a beginner and this is way too complicated to me :( Can I sum it to this: it prevents two writes at same time, but without using synchronized and locks? Later on I will return to this for sure.

Comment: You're more than welcome :)  — „*...Can I sum it to this: it prevents two writes at same time...*“ — By Jove, I've think s/he's got it! :) — „*...I don't quite get it...*“ — But you actually do. I've edited the *TL;DR* to paraphrase it to be closer in wording to your own correct intepretation. — „*Later on I will return to this for sure*“ — A capital idea, old chum! Absolutely! It's a very good question. And I'm grateful to you for asking it. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks a lot once again! Can I ask one more thing? :) Does this have anything to do with lock free algorithm? Is that the thing I am missing here? Is it how all Concurrent implementations work? :)

Comment: Thanks! — „*Does this have anything to do with lock free algorithm?*“ You're probably thinking of [*Lock-freedom*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm#Lock-freedom). Or [*Liveness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liveness). They're all properties of concurrent applications. They have *something* to do with each other. But they have  different concerns. [*Read the code to see how the implementations work*](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/fb7064dc63f9/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/). And [*JCIP*](http://jcip.net/contents.html) explains it very well.

Comment: Damn it, this Java is much deeper than I expected. Hate when on my question I have to learn 20 new things. Hope there will come one day when it looks so easy..

Comment: „*Hate when on my question I have to learn 20 new things...*“ — You don't actually *have to* learn absolutely everything. You will know more than you need to know if just read only the Javadoc, the source code I linked to and the JCIP book. Try it. Be patient with yourself. And you'll do just swell.